# SCSS Susy Configuration Settings

Tags: sass, codekit, susy

I am trying replicate a Bootstrap equivalent grid to my project. I love the idea but am having trouble with the config. I am using Codekit, on the latest version.

I want the grid to use the following:

- box-sizing: border-box;
- 15px gutter each side of a grid item
- No un-need margin (unless @include push(); is used).
- 12 Column Grid Default

These are my current settings:

```css
$susy: (
    container:          1170px,
    columns:            12,
    gutter:             .25,
    global-box-sizing:  border-box,
    output:             isolate
);
```

At the moment when I want to create a 5 column grid:

```css
.members{

  &--li{
    @include span(1 of 5);
  }

 }
```

I expected this:

```css
.members--li{
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
}
```

But got this:

```css
.members--li{
  width: 16.6666666667%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 4.1666666667%;
}
```

I am not sure where the margin right comes from, due to this addition it will never be a 5 column grid, I also expected 20% width. I am aware that the default is 12 columns above but I have set 1 of 5.

Comment: It seems to me that you're not accounting for the gutter.  You can't have 5 elements be 20% wide *and* have space between them.

Comment: I need the gutter to be within the element, not external. Similar to the Bootstrap grid.

Answer (score 0):

Ah that's a bit tricky. Was in the same situation and wrote some mixins to generate a bootstrap like grid with susy and breakpoint. Not yet perfect but doing a job ^^

checkout: http://sassmeister.com/gist/toh82/6d31d28888e930783f02

So take it, change the Breakpoint values as you wish and maybe it helps you. Currently there is the iteration for the container sizes missing in my gist, if this is a problem, let me know.

One of the main things to achieve the BS-Grid is `gutter-position: inside` and the different `container max-width`.